# Conditional transformation of Pandas DataFrame into negative, zero, and positive with epsilon precision

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transformation

I want a data frame consisting of numeric values transformed into three specific symbols depending on whether the value is negative, zero or positive. In addition, the check should be influenced by an epsilon value to control what is considered zero.

```
csv = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
df = csv.iloc[:, :].diff()
df = df.iloc[1:,:] # remove the first row of nans
```

I tried the following

```
neg = df < -eps
zer = abs(df) <= eps
pos = df > eps
df[neg] = 'neg'
df[zer] = 'zer'
df[pos] = 'pos'
```

Which worked for some time, but when `eps` reached a certain value, the following error was thrown `TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value`

I then tried the following:

```
df.transform(lambda x: ('neg' if x < -eps else 'zer') if abs(x) <= eps else 'pos')
```

Resulting error `ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 0')`

I have two questions:

1. Why do I get a TypeError only when `eps` becomes large, but works for, e.g `eps = 0`?
2. How to perform this transformation?

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataframe and an expected output, in other words, a [mcve]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FWIW, I'd probably use `where` to push near-zero values to zero, use `np.sign` to get me a frame of 0, 1, and -1, and then map the result:

```
In [132]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (5,5)))

In [133]: df
Out[133]: 
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.108927 -0.728913 -0.369125 -0.670461  0.941319
1 -0.075262  0.412293  0.893267 -0.911717 -0.489222
2 -0.363191 -0.019171  0.541484  0.933258 -0.742260
3 -0.943218 -0.326041 -0.817188  0.339880  0.830269
4 -0.374525  0.895200 -0.792452 -0.725313  0.190894

In [134]: np.sign(df.where(df.abs() > 0.3, 0)).replace({0: "zer", 1: "pos", -1: "neg"})
Out[134]: 
     0    1    2    3    4
0  zer  neg  neg  neg  pos
1  zer  pos  pos  neg  neg
2  neg  zer  pos  pos  neg
3  neg  neg  neg  pos  pos
4  neg  pos  neg  neg  zer
```

Comment: That works, do you also know why I get a TypeError in my case (question 1)?